# Using correctly the verb "preach"

Tags: verbs

Can I write "Who will you preach then?" (after something has happened)

Or should I write "Who will you preach to, then?"

Also, is there a shorter way to say it?

Comment: "Preach" has two slightly different versions (I'm thinking transitive and intransitive, but I forgot all that stuff about 30 years ago.)  But when you "preach X" then "X" is presumably some doctrine, whereas when you "preach to X" then "X" is some sort of audience.  So, "what will you preach", and "who will you preach to".  (Although maybe is should be "whom will you preach to" -- I can't remember that rule either.)

Comment: You should put it up as an answer, not a comment

Comment: I don't like to make it an answer unless I can quote the rules somehow.  Someone else will no doubt come along who can tell you the rules that apply.

Comment: I voted to close this as general reference because the definition of _preach_, as provided by most dictionaries, is "to give or deliver a sermon" or something similar. The direct object of _preach_, _give_, _deliver_, etc, is _what_ is being delivered; you can also use _to X_ to specify to whom it is being given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one (*"Who will you preach then?"*) is not correct. When used as a transitive verb, *preach* takes its subject matter, not its audience as an object.

Any of the following would be correct:

- *Who will you preach to, then?*
  This is a question about the audience, and is typical of how the question would be formed by native speakers.
- *Whom will you preach to, then?*
  This uses the more proper form "Whom" -- which is often dropped by English speakers.
- *To whom will you preach, then?*
  This might be used in some cases -- but you would *never* hear native speakers say "To who ..."; if they put the preposition in front of the pronoun, they would always use "whom".
- *What will you preach, then?*
  This is a question about the subject matter.
- *What, and to whom, will you preach, then?*
  This covers both the subject matter and the audience.
- *What will you preach, and who(m) will you preach to, then?*
  Same as above